# VS Code Flutter Creating new project gets stuck at resolving dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart, ubuntu

Not my first time creating a flutter project, but when I started VS Code today and tried creating a flutter project (View->Command Palette->New Project), it gets stuck at `Resolving Dependencies...`

I already uninstalled and reinstalled the extensions in VS Code and flutter from `snap` but it's still the same.

I am using ubuntu as my OS.

EDIT:

it's getting stuck at the `flutter pub get` part

EDIT:

I did `flutter pub get -v` and it's getting stuck at `GET https://pub.dev/api/packages/web`

but pinging pub.dev in the terminal shows connection without packet loss

I tried changing my internet from wifi to cable and it's the same.

However I tried installing flutter in a different computer running windows using the same wired connection and was able to proceed.

Comment: What's your flutter version?

Comment: @AppSolves 3.16.7